# Assign value to index of a list for list with a variable name

Tags: r, list

I have a list that is named using `assign` and `paste` as seen below:

```
var1 <- "test"
var2 <- "test2"
assign(paste(var1, var2), vector("list", 5))
```

I want to assign a value to the first index of this list, but

```
assign(get(paste(var1, var2))[[1]], "value")
```

does not work. How could this be done?

Thanks!

Comment: You should really avoid using get and assign in general. It would be much easier if you stored related values in a names list rather than a bunch of separate variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest an alternative approach using `append`:

```
lst <- list(two="two", three="three")
lst <- append(lst, list(one="one"), 0)

lst
$one
[1] "one"

$two
[1] "two"

$three
[1] "three"
```

From what I can see in your problem, there is no reason why this syntax would not also work in your case.

Comment: How would I append a data frame to a list in this way? It seems to be converting the data frame into a list first, then appending it. Thanks!

Comment: @KeshavM I am not seeing this behavior, at least not [in this simple demo](http://rextester.com/ZPWFD27215).  Maybe you can clarify where you are having this problem.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to add list() to the value I was appending to the list. Thank you for your help!